# In Terraria do the corrupt walls and hallowed walls count towards the dryad percentage?

Tags: terraria

I know the background walls can't spread but I want to know if they count because currently the corruption percentage is at 1% and has been for a while, I've checked literally everywhere for hallowed and corruption on TEdit and have seen nothing else.

Do the corrupted or hallowed background walls count towards the dryad's corruption percentage? If it counts I can finally relax.

Comment: I’ve never thought to try and verify this myself, but I’ve always just removed the walls, mostly using the Clentaminator. Simply as seeing they are corruption or hallowed blocks I would imagine so. Either way, there’s no harm in trying to get rid of them regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Yes corrupted walls do count as percentage. Also corruption doesn't start spreading fast until after you kill the Wall Of Flesh. Once you do that the hallow is released and both the corruption and the hallow start spreading pretty quickly. It slows again after you beat Planatara but it still spreads quickly.